Dafny error proving assertion on an unmodified array
The below Dafny method simply asserts that for every index i, there exists an index j such that the input array elements are equal.  I am curious why the particular invariant and assertion does not hold since I am not modifying the array. Isn't supposed to be obvious to the Dafny? Am I missing something.
method test(a:array<int>) returns (b:array<int>)
requires a.Length > 0
ensures b.Length > 0
ensures a.Length == b.Length
ensures forall k: int::0 <= k < a.Length ==> b[k] == a[k]
{
    var i:= 0;
    var j := 0;

    while i < a.Length
    invariant i >=0 && j>=0
    invariant i==j
    invariant i <= a.Length && j <= a.Length
    invariant forall k: int::0 <= k < i ==> exists l | 0 <= l < j:: a[k] == a[l]
    decreases (a.Length - i)
    decreases (a.Length - j)
    {
       assert forall k: int::0 <= k < i ==> exists l | 0 <= l < j:: a[k] == a[l];
       i := i+1;
       j := j+1;
    }
    return a;
}

I tried to put assertions at different points in the while loop but with no result. I think this is a simple program that reads the input array. In the worst case, i == j. But for some reason that I don't understand, the verification fails.
Any insight into why it fails and a possible hint on how to proceed will help. Note that I do want to retain the invariant using exists

Here is a version that asserts the loop invariant after the loop. It differs to the previous versions in that it externalises the predicate used within the universal quantification. Quantifiers are a common source of unintuitive behaviour and this workaround typically helps with such issues.
predicate P(a: array<int>, k: int, i: int)
reads a
requires i <= a.Length
requires 0 <= k < i
{
    exists l | 0 <= l < i :: a[k] == a[l]
}

method test(a:array<int>) returns (b:array<int>)
requires a.Length > 0
ensures b.Length > 0
ensures a.Length == b.Length
ensures forall k: int | 0 <= k < a.Length :: b[k] == a[k]
{
    var i:= 0;
    var j := 0;

    while i < a.Length
     invariant i >= 0 && j >= 0
     invariant i == j 
     invariant i <= a.Length && j <= a.Length
     invariant forall k: int | 0 <= k < i :: P(a, k, i)
     decreases (a.Length - i)
     decreases (a.Length - j)
    {
       assert a[i] == a[j];
       i := i+1;
       j := j+1;
    }
    assert forall k: int | 0 <= k < i :: P(a, k, i);
    return a;
}


Thanks! This is indeed very helpful. I am not aware of the issues associated with triggers.

This seems like simple invariant or assertion which Dafny should figure out itself but it is not apparently.
To help Dafny you can add assert a[i] == a[j]; in body of while as first statement.
    while i < a.Length
     invariant i >= 0 && j >= 0
     invariant i == j 
     invariant i <= a.Length && j <= a.Length
     invariant forall k: int :: 0 <= k < i ==> exists l | 0 <= l < j :: a[k] == a[l]
     decreases (a.Length - i)
     decreases (a.Length - j)
    {
       assert a[i] == a[j];
       i := i+1;
       j := j+1;
    }


So that solves the invariant problem but not the assertion. It beats me why. Here is the issue: if I use the assert that copies the invariant, assert forall k: int :: 0 <= k < i ==> exists l | 0 <= l < j :: a[k] == a[l]; after the loop right before return a, the assertion does not verify. It is really puzzling because it is supposed to be loop invariant and it should hold at the loop exit!

This seems like some bug. You can file an issue here https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues

It does indeed seem like an issue. Thanks for the suggestion.
